# Keras: shape error when using validation data

Tags: keras

Trying to add validation to `model.fit`, but whenever I do I get an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (6, 4, 10) for Tensor 'lstm_input_1:0', which has shape '(32, 4, 10)'
```

#### Model:

```
data_dim = 10
timesteps = 4
batch_size = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.5)
```

What could be the error? If I remove `validation_split` the training works just fine. I've also tried to manually split my training set into two and add it with `validation_data=(x_val, y_val)` but I got the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that you hard code the `batch_size` value of your inputs. You have fixed it to 32 and then when you try and validate your model, the validation data is sent with a batch of 6 samples, this might be because you don't have enough validation data or maybe because the number of sample isn't a multiple of 32... However, I would let the `batch_size` free if I was you. Like this:

```
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
```

You specify `input_shape` instead of `batch_input_shape`. That way, your network will accept any size of batch, every layer down in the stream of your model are made to adapt to any batch_size if not hardcoded.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad, I've just made a typo in the copy. The actual output is this: `Train on 768 samples, validate on 768 samples` and `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (768, 4, 10) for Tensor 'lstm_input_1:0', which has shape '(32, 4, 10)'`. 768 is clearly a multiply of 32, that's why I don't understand the error.

Comment: The validation isn't fed by batches then. When it's validating it sends the whole validation set as one batch and predicts on it. Hence the error... is the fix working? Changing to input_shape instead of batch_input_shape

Comment: Yeah, that's working, although I have to remove `stateful=True` as well.

Comment: Why is that? You don't need stateful or you got batch related constraints?

Comment: If you really need your validation to be made by batch you can use fit_generator, then you can use a generator for the training data and the validation data. That helps you manage how the batches are going in and the validation is made using the batches. :)

Comment: It's because `ValueError: If a RNN is stateful, a complete input_shape must be provided (including batch size).`, not sure the `fit_generator` would solve this issue, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You can always try, if your generators ALWAYS outputs batches of the same size then you can fix the input batch size using batch_input_shape.